# Why doesn't my IIS module mapping configuration show up in applicationHost.config?

Tags: iis, configuration, iis-8.5, isapi

I have the following structure:

```
myServer
    Sites
        Default Web Site
            myVirtualDirectory
                myApplication    <- added to handler Mappings here
```

Under "myApplication", I have added an IsapiModule to a specific dll. However, when I export my IIS configurations using the steps outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/493373/2687324, I don't see any references to my dll under `<handlers>` or anywhere in `applicationHost.config`.

Is this configuration store elsewhere?

Comment: Have you checked the web.config files in your application folder or site folder?

Comment: I'm not sure where that is, but I looked at the locations indicated on https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc754617(v=ws.10).aspx.